# Базы данных, C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio

Cитуация такая - надо сделать так чтобы при записи в Базу Данных вылетал MessageBox и в нём просто одно слово "Успешно". Только как это сделать не могу додуматься. Прошу помощи!!

Comment: `MessageBox.Show("Успешно");`

Comment: А условия не надо? Типа проверка на ошибку?

Comment: можешь и добавить условие `if(succes == true) MessageBox.Show("Успешно");`. Зависит от твоей задачи. Отредактируй вопрос и добавь часть кода с добавлением чего-либо в базу данных, сформулируй задачу поточнее и тогда можно будет ответить конкретнее.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: ниже ответ, вот возьми тот код в свой проект

Answer (score 1):

А как пишешь в таблицу? Пробуй так

```
try
{
  //запись в таблицу
  messagebox.show("ok");
}
catch
{
  mesaagebox.show("не ok");
}
```